# Can I use "were" in this sentence?

Tags: verb-usage

My sentence is,

"I thought it **were** your friends (that) you went out with."

I used the be-verb **were** in this sentence because **it** refers to **your friends**.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to use *was* there because the subject of the sentence, *it*, is grammatically a singular entity. Linguists call this type of *it* an impersonal subject. It semantically has no meaning. It's only there for the sake of grammatical completeness.

Examples:

> I thought **it was** you who called me last night.
>   I thought **it was** your friends that you went out with.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of sentence is known as an '*it*-cleft'. The *it*-cleft emphasizes the  element that "it" is equated with:

> I thought **it was your friends** you went out with (not your mother).
>
> I thought **it was the red one** you wanted (not the blue one).

But the verb will always be singular, "was". "it was", "it is".